# Cron job posts 40-50 new posts to WordPress then fails with transport error - HTTP status code was not 200

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have cron job that runs a PHP xmlrpc script that calls `metaWeblog.newPost` in a loop, to make posts to a WordPress site. The posts get added successfully, until, after typically 40 or 50 posts, the script stop with this error:

> transport error - HTTP status code was not 200

The error log contained this (I have removed the ip address):

> (9)Bad file descriptor: [client :44726] mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function

When I check `phpinfo` I see that Zend Memory Manager is enabled and `memory_limit` is 64M.

What should I be looking at to solve this?

Comment: I wonder if you have overloaded the web server, by making too many requests in succession. Try putting a small pause in between each one - I assume that, since this is on a cron, a one second delay between each won't be too slow for your purposes?

Comment: Thanks - a one second delay did not fix it, but a two second delay did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A one second delay did not fix it, and a two second delay fixed it most of the time. A three second delay fixed it.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to self-accept this answer (by clicking the tick on the left hand side). For the sake of interest (and assuming you're on a GNU/Linux platform) if you look at `ps aux | grep apache` when posting with no delay (or `top` is good, to get a live view) you'll see a bunch of web processes being spawned to handle the apparent spike in traffic.

Comment: Also, since you are running from cron, xmlrpc is quite an inefficient way to do this. It is better to write a PHP script that writes posts using the WordPress native functions - you don't need to push each one through Apache to do so, so it is much faster, and there is no need to add delays between each one.